# What does the "-s" mean in "doxygen -s -g ini"? Any guesses?

Tags: command-line, doxygen

[image]

When generating the configuration file, is there a reason to use
"doxygen -s -g ini"
instead of just
"doxygen -g ini"?

Comment: `doxygen --help` doesn't provide any info…?

Comment: Oh thank you, "If -s is specified the comments of the configuration items in the config file will be omitted." Yeah I'm really new to command lines. Thanks!

Comment: When having problem with option of a program always try options like: `--help`, `-h`, -?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [online doxygen manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/doxygen):

> If -s is specified the comments in the config file will be omitted. If configName is omitted 'Doxyfile' will be used as a default.

Comment: There is always someone else who is better. This is a recursive truth.